# Swift - UISearchBar throwing "this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key searchBar"

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

I am new to iOS/Swift programming. I am trying to add a UISearchBar to the ViewController.

I have tried to follow this link http://shrikar.com/swift-ios-tutorial-uisearchbar-and-uisearchbardelegate/

I have defined TableView, TableViewCell, and UISearchBar. I consistently get the same error  this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key searchBar.
I have exhausted all stackoverflow links.
I am enclosing a screenshot of my setup. Appreciate any pointers.

- S[image]

Comment: What is SearchBarViewController? Does it have an `@IBOutlet searchBar` like you have on the pictured ViewController?

Comment: I have a main DashboardViewController that has an IBAction

Comment: Yes. I have a XIB with name "SearchBarViewController" that has IBOutlet. It is being called like this: <br/> (IBAction)SearchBarBtnAcn:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Search bar clicked");

    SearchBarViewController * searchVC = [[SearchBarViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SearchBarViewController" bundle:Nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:searchVC animated:YES];
}

Answer (score 1):

This is normally caused by a link from your storyboard to a non existent property. Double check all the links from objects in your storyboard. Also if you have changed the name or spelling of a property or method it can still have a reference to the old one.

```
                               OR
```

you can delete all the outlet and then reinitialise them. hope it's work for you.

Comment: I tried that. Now I get fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value. <br> I created a new outlet from my xib file to controller code. I still get the same error.